# Any reason why my useEffect logging things twice in React native?

Tags: react-native

why is the value of make and point counting twice instead of once when the condition are met and also why are the console.log log logging twice in the useEffect.

```
//USESTATE SECTION
    const [distanceOfScreenTopToBigCircle, setDistanceOfScreenTopToBigCircle] = useState(700);
  
    //Checking moving ball background color
    const [bigCircleBackgroundColor, setBigCircleBackgroundColor] = useState('grey');

    //This state helps in holding the random color given to moving ball
    const [movingBallColor, setMovingBallColor] = useState();

    //This state is responsible for giving dynamic color values to the bigCircle borders 
    const [borderOrder, setBorderOrder] = useState(['red', 'blue', 'green', 'yellow']);

    //This state hold the value points scored
    const [points, setPoints] = useState(0);

    //This states hold time duration for the rate at which he ball
    //moves. It changes at different conditions.
    const [movingBallTimeDuration, setMovingBallTimeDuration] = useState(2500);

  

    //CONTEXT API...
    //This context variable hold the boolean value to know if the modal pop
    //up alert dialogue box to show. It carries the value of true or false
    //and this values can be toggles around our application as long as the
    //context is imported into the componet. . . . . .  . .
    const {failedContextValue, setFailedContextValue} = useContext(FailedContext);


    const [ballY] = useState(new Animated.Value(0));
    //FUNCTION SECTION . . . . . . . . . .
     //MOVING BALL ANIMATION PART
   
    function movingBallFunction () {

        if (distanceOfScreenTopToBigCircle) { //checks if distanceOfScreenTopToBigCircle isn't null

            //This is linear animation
            Animated.timing(ballY, {
                toValue: distanceOfScreenTopToBigCircle,//This the distance the ball should fall to
                duration: movingBallTimeDuration,//This is for the time the ball should reach the bigCircle
                easing: Easing.linear,
                useNativeDriver: true,

            }).start()//This start() method starts our animation
        
        } 

        //This is to not show the instruction on how to start game when user 
        //have started playing the game, or when the ball is moving already. .
        setShowHowToStartGameInstruction(false)
    
    }  

    //This function is to return the ball to the top when it color
    //matches with borderTop color of the bigCircle at that moment.
    const returnToTop = () => {

        Animated.timing(ballY, {
            toValue: 0,
            duration: 0,
            easing: Easing.linear,
            useNativeDriver: true,
        }).start();


        //Let give random colors to the moving ball onload of page
        //const colors = ['green', 'yellow', 'blue', 'red'];
        const colors = ['red', 'red', 'red']
        const randomColor = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];

        setMovingBallColor(randomColor);


        //let call the moving ball function after 2 sec
        setTimeout(() => {

            movingBallFunction();

        }, 150)
        

    };    


const [make, setMake] = useState(0)
   
    //This effect listens for onchange of postion of the ball
    useEffect(() => {

        //The listener listens for when the ball get to the 
        //big circle position from the top of the mobile screen
        const animationListener = ballY.addListener(({ value }) => {

            //console.log('BallY position is:', value)

            //if the ball has gotten to the big cicle position,
            //let check if the background color of the ball is
            //the same as the borderTopColor of the big circle

            if (value >= distanceOfScreenTopToBigCircle) {

                console.log('on code', bigCircleBordersStyles)

                    console.log('jasmine', borderOrder[0]);
                    console.log('move me', movingBallColor); 
                    
                    //if the movingBallColor is same as borderTop of
                    //bigCircle, let add a point
                    if (movingBallColor === borderOrder[0]) {
                        //fix this tomorrow, it counts twice.
                        setPoints((prevState) => prevState + 1);        
                        console.log('point score is', points);
        setMake((prevState) => prevState + 1);
                        //Let return the ball to the top
                        returnToTop();

                        //Also let set the big circle background of bigCircle
                        //to whatever is the color is the moving ball.
                        setBigCircleBackgroundColor(movingBallColor);
                         
                        console.log('they are the same', borderOrder[0], bigCircleBackgroundColor);
    
                    } else {
    

                        //If falied, let call the store to local storage function
                        storeNewPointNumberToStorage(points); 

                        //If failed, let pop a failed game message (from the modal component).
                        setFailedContextValue(true);


                        console.log('not the same', borderOrder[0], movingBallColor, bigCircleBackgroundColor);
                    }
              
                  
            }

        });

        //This serves a clean up mehanism.
        return () => {
            
            ballY.removeListener(animationListener);

        };
        
  
    }, [ballY, distanceOfScreenTopToBigCircle, borderOrder, bigCircleBackgroundColor]);
```

Answer (score 0):

The useEffect code runs the first time on mount and the second time when you modify any of the useEffect dependencies ([ballY, distanceOfScreenTopToBigCircle, borderOrder, bigCircleBackgroundColor]).

In this case I see you are modifying bigCircleBackgroundColor in the useEffect:  `setBigCircleBackgroundColor(movingBallColor);`
Since its modifying the dependency with a condition before it, I would assume the condition is met when the component first mounts but after the modification and rerender it is not satisfying that condition so it is not triggering another update. Therefore it rerenders only once. Every dependency update will trigger a rerender.

Comment: I am more focused on the console.log('point score is', points); part, the points states add one two twice almost immediately. Same as other console.log in the useEffect, they log to the console two times almost immediately. How do I solve that?

Comment: Is every print line duplicated individually or do they all print again in order?